# Writing rspec to test for error, but error is thrown and stops test from passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rspec

I wrote a test where I expect the result to throw an error.

```
it{ Authentication.create_with_omniauth!(nil, nil).should raise_error }
```

The result indeed throws an error, but the validation fails. Apparently it's throwing an error. :)

```
2) Authentication methods: self.create_with_omniauth!: with bad input 
     Failure/Error: it{ Authentication.create_with_omniauth!(nil, nil).should raise_error }
     ArgumentError:
       ArgumentError
     # ./app/models/authentication.rb:13:in `create_with_omniauth!'
     # ./spec/models/authentication_spec.rb:69:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Now what? How do you test for an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **expect {}.to raise_error** syntax

```
expect { Authentication.create_with_omniauth!(nil, nil) }.to raise_error
```

or

```
lambda { Authentication.create_with_omniauth!(nil, nil) }.should raise_error
```

if you use Rspec 1.X.X

check out documentation

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher#expect-any-error

http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000176

Comment: Hmm...I immediately got `Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for #<Class:0x007fbe9e1f4028>>` I only have it alone by itself `describe "with bad input" do
        expect { Authentication.create_with_omniauth!(nil, nil) }.to raise_error
      end`

Comment: What version of Rspec do you use?
New syntax https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher#expect-any-error

old one http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000176

Comment: Thanks I figured out the problem. For the novice like me, you may wish to amend your answer to specify that the `expect` needs to be inside an `it` block. Silly mistake, but I didn't recognize the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with omniauth, but does something like this work?

```
describe "authentication" do
  context "when nil" do
    let(:nil_authentication) { Authentication.create_with_omniauth!(nil, nil) }
    subject { -> { nil_authentication } }
    it { should raise_error }
  end
end
```